# Ansible, call specific role tasks via tags isn't working, all tasks are being ran

Tags: tags, ansible, roles

I'm using Ansible 2.3.2.0, and am calling a role that is running 4 different tasks.

When I call the role via a playbook, and specify specific tags, the entire role and all tasks are being run. I saw where this was a known issue after ansible 2.0, and the suggested fix was to add a static directive under include statements.   I tried that, but still all tasks were run. 
Here is the role statement in the playbook...

```
roles:
    - {role: ansible-role-auto-deploy, tags: [ 'ami', 'launch_config', 'asg']}
```

And here is the roles' main.yml

```
---

- include: ami.yml
  static: yes
  tags:
    - ami

- include: launch_config.yml
  static: yes
  tags:
    - launch_config

- include: asg.yml
  static: yes
  tags:
    - asg

- include: ami_lc_cleanup.yml
  static: yes
  tags:
    - ami_lc_cleanup
```

When I run this with the roles statement above, I would expect ami, launch_config, and asg tasks to be run, but in addition the ami_lc_cleanup task is also being run.

The tasks all work, I just don't know how to limit which tasks are being run.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get it to work (with being able to specify tasks via tags)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional includes should *not* be defined as static using `static: no`.

**Edit**

Assuming from your comments you misunderstood the `tags` statement in your playbook. This is not to included roles with the defined tags, but to include a role based on tags given at the command line.

Which tags are active in your play is defined by the command line only (as far as I know, I'm still learning ansible, too).

If you want to define a condition for the role in your playbook you should use variables/facts for that.

Call your playbook using `ansible-playbook --tags ami,launch_config,asg` to skip the cleanup process. When defining the tags in your playbook you prevent the role from being executed when `ami_lc_cleanup` is defined as a tag on the commandline without any of the other three tags.

Comment: That doesn't help much, can you elaborate?

Comment: You have the includes defined as `static: yes`, but it should be `static: no` when using conditionals like `when` or in your case `tags`.

Comment: I tried switching to static: no, and no difference.  Using the --list-tags and --list-tasks options, I can see that the first 3 tasks are being run with TAGS:[ami, asg, and launch_config] and then when it gets to the last task, its being run even though its not tagged in the calling playbook.  So it must be inheriting the tag from the role...

Comment: ok, it does work, if I set the playbook role line to:
     - {role: ansible-role-auto-deploy}    and then call the playbook with --tags ami,asg,launch_config

then it only runs the specified tasks referenced via --tags

Comment: Ok, going back and reading the ansible documenation on tags, roles, etc, as it is not very clear on the exact usage.  Love ansible, sometimes hate their documentation